# Does different android phones have different limits on the number of bluetooth SPP profile devices they can connect to?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been able to connect to multiple bluetooth SPP devices simultaneously. But I am able to connect to a max of 3 bluetooth devices in Samsung Galaxy S I9003 phone. And in my Galaxy S II,  I am able to connect to only 2 devices simultaneously.

Is there different limits for different devices. As I understood the limit to parallel connections is 7 for the underlying Bluez stack. Is there any way to overcome this limit ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there different limits for different devices.

I am sure that that is the case. I've seen device manufacturers heavily modify Android OS for whatever reason. I.E. switching Bluetooth ON and OFF programmatically requires `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission on Galaxy Nexus, while on many Samsung devices it also requires `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`. And the same thing with WiFi. So I am not surprised that Samsung has different max number of simultaneous Bluetooth connections for different devices.

> Is there any way to overcome this limit ?

In theory - yes. But you will have to obtain Android OS source code, modify the max number of parallel connections, and then build a new system image and install it on your device. I'm afraid this won't be easy.